# Error _OBJC_CLASS ...?

Tags: iphone

Can anybody tell me why my program is showing this error?

```
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_MKMapView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-MKMapView in RRMapsViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
```

Comment: Ran,why you do not accept the answer if you get the solution?

Comment: @Ishu StackOverflow has a limit on how soon you can accept an answer as correct (15 minutes, I believe).

Comment: @Dave DeLong, Ok this is the thing which i should know. thanx sir.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to link the MapKit framework into your project.

Comment: @dave : i am getting the same issue i have imported                        `#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>`                                                And getting the following error:                                  **the Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MKMapView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in maptryViewController.o ** Can you help me?

Comment: @SiddarthHailstorm Importing is insufficient.  You must link in the framework as well.  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaLibrarytoaTarget.html